# Doubly linked list remove item at index that runs O(n)?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Can someone explain to me the part how the traversing happens and is there another better way to do removals ? Thank you.

```
public T removeAt(int index) {
    // Make sure the index provided is valid
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int i;
    Node<T> trav;

    // Search from the front of the list
    if (index < size / 2) {
      for (i = 0, trav = head; i != index; i++) {
        trav = trav.next;
      }
      // Search from the back of the list
    } else
      for (i = size - 1, trav = tail; i != index; i--) {
        trav = trav.prev;
      }

    return remove(trav);
  }
```

Comment: We traverse either from the front or back depending on which half of the list the index we want to remove falls at.

Comment: what about the two conditions in the for loop ? trav = tail and i !=index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to locate an index in a linked list and remove the element at that index. Unlike an array, a linked list does not provide random access in O(1) and hence this operation is always O(n). But can we do better?

We know the size of the linked list (the number of elements in the list) and the index we want to remove. Using these, we can reduce the traversal to half - **n / 2**.

We check if the element to be removed at `index` falls into the first half or the second half of the list. This is done by the check `index < size / 2`. If it is in the first half, we start the traversal from the head and go forward until we reach the element to remove.

If the element is on the second half of the list, we start from the end and traverse backwards until we reach the element to remove.

---

```
for (i = 0, trav = head; i != index; i++) {
    trav = trav.next;
  }
```

`trav = head` - assigns head to `trav`, a local variable. Here `i` starts at 0, and goes till `index`<sup>1</sup>. Now, we call the routine `remove` that does the removal (not shown in your code). Its job will be to remove the element pointed to by `trav`

The logic for traversing from the end is also similar.

```
for (i = size - 1, trav = tail; i != index; i--) {
    trav = trav.prev;
  }
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It might appear that we stop before the element we want to remove. On careful observation, we can find that the loop terminates when `i = index`. But we would have reached `index` when `i` was at `index - 1` by executing `trav = trav.next`.

Example: Say size = 10 and index = 2.. Starting at head

`i = 0`, move to index 1 - `i++`

`i = 1`, move to index 2 - `i++`

`i = 2`, break the loop

Now, we are pointing at the element at index 2 (3rd element).